# How can I use Kinetic.Transforms and apply them to a node?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I've been searching around for more than one hour. But I can't find a clear and suitable guide to get a Kinetic.Tranform from a node, then apply transformation to it's matrix, to finally apply it back to the node.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15045869/3398633) but it doesn't say how you can get a Kinetic.Transform from a node nor you can apply a Kinetic.Transform to a node in order to modify the node. The documentation of Kineticjs is totally unclear about it and there is no tutorial for this in [HTML 5 Canvas tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/).

So if someone could write here a guide on which method Should be used and in which order. It'll help me a lot.

Comment: `Kinetic.Transforms` is like "private" class. So documentation is poor. May be you need to use just `position`, `scale`, `rotation`?

Comment: @lavrton Indeed those 3 methods could do the job in most of the cases. But I ask this question more for curiosity purpose. But in somes cases, like rotation around an arbitrary point without offset, it could help.